# Multithreading and Serial Ports

Tags: c#, multithreading, serial-port, modbus

Ok..this will be lengthy but I need to explain some background first.

This part of my software is for sorting items running down a conveyor belt.
I am using Modbus for the conveyor belt.  Modbus will open gates at a specific time to let an item go through the gate. Items will go through certain gates based on weight.

I am monitoring a sensor to determine when an item is on a scale. When the sensor is blocked, the item is weighed and sent to the appropriate gate. Timers are set to open/close the gate.

My code will work for this..the problem is, it will not work for multiple items.  By that I mean, while a gate is open the sensor is not being monitored until the gate is closed.  So while Item A is on the way to the gate, Item B will not get weighed on the scale when it blocks the sensor.  I could have up to 8 items on the line at once. Here is the code I am running now:

```
private void SensorThread_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    if (SensorThread.CancellationPending == true)
        e.Cancel = true;
    else
    {
        ReadSensor();
    }    
}

private void SensorThread_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    //if sensor is blocked
    if (sensorstatus == 0)
    {
        //the timers just start the thread
        scaleTimer.Start();
    }
    else
    {
        sensorTimer.Start();
    }
}

private void ScaleThread_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
  if (ScaleThread.CancellationPending == true)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
    else
    {
        ReadScale();
        //SaveWeight();
        prevgate = gate;
        gate = DetermineGate();
        SetOpenDelay();
        SetDuration();
    }
  }

private void ScaleThread_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    //if gate = 0, this means the weight of meat on scale 
    //is not in any weight range. Meat runs off the end.
    if (gate == 0)
    {
        txtStatus.Invoke(new UpdateStatusCallback(UpdateStatus), new object[] { meatweight.ToString() + 
                                                                                "lbs is out of range"});
        sensorTimer.Start();
    }
    else
    {
      //open gate
      //then close gate
    }
  }
```

This code works fine, I just need to be able to account for multiple items on the line.
Any suggestions????

I've also tried the following:

```
private void SensorThread_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    if (SensorThread.CancellationPending == true)
        e.Cancel = true;
    else
    {
        ReadSensor();
    }    
}    

private void SensorThread_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
  sensorTimer.Start();
}

  private void ScaleThread_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
  if (ScaleThread.CancellationPending == true)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
    else
    {   
        //sensor blocked
        if (sensorstatus == 0)
        {
          ReadScale();
          //SaveWeight();
          prevgate = gate;
          gate = DetermineGate();
          SetOpenDelay();
          SetDuration();

          //if gate = 0, this means the weight of meat on scale 
          //is not in any weight range. Meat runs off the end.
          if (gate == 0)
          {
            txtStatus.Invoke(new UpdateStatusCallback(UpdateStatus), new object[] { meatweight.ToString() + 
                                                                                "lbs is out of range"});
          }
          else
          {
            //open gate
            //close gate
          }
    }
}

private void ScaleThread_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
   scaleTimer.Start();
}
```

When I did this, I started both threads when the start button was pressed.  I get all kinds of exceptions and the program eventually throws the SEHException and crashes. The other errors I get say "Serial port already opened" or "I/O Error".

Comment: Is the problem that the scale thread blocks during DetermineGate(), SetOpenDelay() and SetDuration()?  I am not completely understanding your code yet. It looks like it is still very procedural even though you are using threads -- it looks like the threads are always waiting on each other. Is this what is happening?

Comment: FYI, here is a great link on multithreading in C#: http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/threads/index.shtml

Comment: This is my first time multithreading. I needed it where my GUI wouldn't lock up. I'm not sure what you mean by "the thread scale blocks" The threads are waiting on each other..but when I tried to fix it, I just got a bunch of errors (see my edit). I need this software to be able to run a conveyor belt. It should account for items passing by the sensor at a rate of say...1 item every 3 sec. So all of the gates should be opening/closing as the item arrives at its gate.  I know this sounds confusing..do you understand what I'm trying to accomplish? Thanks for the link

Answer (score 2):

I think you need something like this. Don't know if the locks are needed but I added them for safety since you are getting errors

```
private void SensorThread_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) 
{
    int sensor = 1;
    while(!SensorThread.CancellationPending == true) 
    {
        int newSensor;
        lock(this)
        {
            newSensor = ReadSensor(); 
        }

        //sensor state changed
        if(newSensor != sensor)
        {
            //sensor was 1 and changed to 0
            if(newSensor==0)
            {
               scaleTimer.Start(); 
            }
            sensor = newSensor;
        }
        Thread.Sleep(1);
    }
    e.Cancel = true; 
}     

private void ScaleThread_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) 
{ 
    //sensor blocked 
    //if (sensorstatus == 0) 
    { 
        lock(this)
        {
            ReadScale(); 
        }
        //SaveWeight(); 
        prevgate = gate; 
        gate = DetermineGate(); 
        lock(this)
        {
            SetOpenDelay(); 
            SetDuration(); 
        }

      //if gate = 0, this means the weight of meat on scale  
      //is not in any weight range. Meat runs off the end. 
      if (gate == 0) 
      { 
        txtStatus.Invoke(new UpdateStatusCallback(UpdateStatus), new object[] { meatweight.ToString() +  
                                                                            "lbs is out of range"}); 
      } 
      else 
      { 
        lock(this)
        {
        //open gate 
        }
        lock(this)
        {
        //close gate 
        }
      } 
  }
```

Comment: so should the newSensor start out as a true value? can you elaborate a little on what you're doing here?

Comment: Fixed the newSensor initialization. The idea, as others have suggested, is that the sensor thread loops checking the sensor and when it detects a change in the state it triggers the scale thread.

Comment: I'll give this a shot and see what happens.  Thanks!

Comment: Didn't get anywhere with that. I'm pretty much at a standstill. Going to have to call somebody in to look at this for me. Wish I wasn't such a noob haha.

Comment: Are you getting an exception or just nothing is happening? Made a few changes.

Comment: Exceptions. My exception says serial port is already open. I have 2 dedicated com ports set up, using one for my scale, and one for modbus. The threads are just looping and keep hitting the com port to read the scale or read/write to modbus.

Comment: Also it throws an SEHException after running for a few minutes and the program crashes and burns. This software will be running pretty much 24/7, so I can't have that

Comment: I would recommend a completely separate static object to do your locking. That way, everything locks on the same object every time. If you have multiple instances trying to lock on themselves to access a shared resource, you don't really have a lock at all. Everything needs to lock on the same object. It can be as simple as: `private static object lockObject = new object();`

Comment: ... reading through the code, I see that the two threads won't try to access the same resource, so your locking is probably okay. In that case, they don't need to lock at all, however. I would change it to a static object just to be safe, since it will survive refactors better.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that your best bet is probably to create a dedicated thread to sit on each serial port.  Such an approach will neither require, nor forbid, any similarity in how the ports are handled, will avoid any interference in operation between the ports, and will be scalable within reasonable bounds (using a thread for each of 32 ports would be fine; using a thread for each of 1,000 would be bad).  Although one should avoid creating threads which will simply run for a short time and quit, or creating really huge numbers of threads, using a dedicated thread for each serial port will ensure that when data comes in there will be a thread ready to handle it.

Comment: I attempted this. I had a thread dedicated to the sensor and one dedicated to the scale. The scale thread only grabbed the weight if the sensor was blocked (something was on the scale). Then once I got the weight I would spawn a thread to handle the gates. I would never make it to that thread though because I got errors with reading the scale and sensor. Those two threads wouldn't work together. They are on different COM ports and everything, so I'm not sure whats up

Comment: My suggestion would have been to launch all the threads at startup and simply leave them running.  Starting up threads is expensive.  Leaving a thread continuously executing code uselessly is very expensive.  Letting a thread sit blocked waiting for I/O, however, is comparatively much cheaper.  Not so cheap that one should have hundreds running for no reason, but cheap enough that eight would generally be no big deal.

Answer (score 1):

I notice that you don't have any loops in your thread's DoWork methods. That would be a great place to start. The worker thread should be a loop that doesn't return until CancellationPending is set to true.  They won't loop on their own just because you have it in a thread -- the thread will run until it is done, then exit.

Edited to add: What you seem to be missing is that you need to split up the code that monitors the scale and the code that opens and closes the gate.  One way to do that would be to have an infinite loop that monitors the scale, and when it detects something, it starts a new thread that handles opening and closing the gate.

Comment: Thanks Charlie (and Tom) for the upvote. From what I understood I think the loop is "caused" by one thread calling the other.

Comment: Gotcha, but then the OP is still using procedural code -- one method won't run until the other method calls it. The idea in threading is to have one code that runs independent of another, and when it finds something that is lengthy (like opening and closing the gates), it spawns that work into a new thread. Or am I missing something?

Comment: I loop the thread in the RunWorkerCompleted method. It starts a timer which calls the thread after it ticks.