# Serial Port : It is possible to send & receive multiple signals at a time

Tags: c#, serial-port

In serial port communication my requirement is to send & receive multiple signals at a time. I have used threading concept, when one thread is running with serial port - mode open to read signal it work fine,but when I tried to execute second thread for sending data to com port. Here I get error message -

Exception Type="System.UnauthorizedAccessException

Source="System.IO.Ports.InternalResources.WinIOError

Access to the port 'COM9' is denied.

Please help!!!

Comment: Show your code. Do you use a shared instance, or create a new instance per thread? Try searching, you need one communication thread, a blocking collection and write to the collection and let the single thread handle the communication. [Multithreading and Serial Ports](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9914948/multithreading-and-serial-ports) and so on.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible the way you describe it.

You can only have one handle open at a time for a particular port.

In principle, you can use that same handle from multiple threads simultaneously to send data, but what do you envision will happen at the receiving end if it receives 3 bytes from sending thread A, then 2 bytes from sending thread B, then another byte from thread A, and so on?

If you use a well-defined packet protocol (which can be your own or a standard one), you can use a lock to prevent other threads from grabbing the port while sending out a complete packet.